# Unable to open images when Imagemagick updated from 6.9.2.8 to 7.0.7.4

Tags: imagemagick

I updated the ImageMagick library in my application. Since then my code is not able to generate images.

Is there any special change or option I need to consider while installing? I am replacing convert.exe in my app.

Comment: Use magick.exe in place of convert.exe. Check that you have delegates for your image types using `magick.exe -version` and see what libraries you are using? How did you update Imagemagick -- from binary or from source? Did you get it from Imagemagick or some other source? What command are you using that fails? There are a number of changes from IM 6 to IM 7. See http://imagemagick.org/script/porting.php#cli.  Where did you install IM 7? You may need to use the full path to magick.exe

Comment: @fmw42 So I should not select legacy components (convert.exe) while installing? I am shipping this with my msi. I installed from ImageMagick website.

Comment: If your application needs legacy commands using convert.exe, then you should install the legacy components and continue to use convert.exe. If you do not need to use convert.exe and can use the newer IM 7, then change your command syntax to magick.exe.

Comment: So I just replaced `convert.exe` with the new version obtained after installing the installer. So all references stay intact and didn't change any as they refer to `convert.exe`. It stops working then. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Did you install the legacy components? Did you install IM 7 or IM 6? You may want to go back and install IM 6 rather than IM 7 if it has problems with the legacy components.

Comment: So I had IM 6.9.2 and I want to update to IM 7.x latest. While installing IM 7.x I checked on the option of including legacy components so yes legacy was installed and that's how I could see convert.exe in the `C:/ProgramFiles/IM Folder`. Also, when I try to update to even the version after 6.9.2 but before 7.x so 6.9.9 I guess, I had the same problem and my images stopped rendering.

Comment: I am not aware of any difference between 6.9.2 and 6.9.9 that might affect your issue.  What were the last parts of the versions 6.9.2.x and 6.9.9.x? Sorry I am not a Windows user, so do not know much about installing on Windows. In Windows, there is a convert.exe that is not Imagemagick. Typically Windows users rename the IM convert or create some kind of symbolic link or environment variable to make sure you get the IM convert when you want it and not the Windows convert. Perhaps that is your issue.

Comment: @fmw42 hmm. I couldn't find anything like that online. Still not sure why it's not working and how to resolve.

Comment: Check Imagemagick in command line mode to see if you can find out what is happening. Perhaps you need to put the full path to convert.exe in your commands. Do something simple like `convert.exe logo: logo.png` or `path2/convert.exe logo: logo.png`. Or just `convert.exe -version`.  Do any of those work? If using Imagemagick 7, then change convert to magick and try those again.